# Should I need to specify a timeout when using Apache's HttpClient?

Tags: java, android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

The default values are infinite.

But as I am using Apache Client [1] in Android, since mobile network is always unreliable, so should I need to set the `http.socket.timeout` and `http.connection.timeout`?

If yes, what value I should set? Is **one minute** a suitable value for mobile network (e.g. 3G)?

[1] http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use the [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) you can always set the same timeout values, namely:

```
// Default connection and socket timeout of 60 seconds.  Tweak to taste.
private static final int SOCKET_OPERATION_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000;
```

This constant is used for a lot of timeouts,

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, SOCKET_OPERATION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SOCKET_OPERATION_TIMEOUT);
```

and also used when calling `SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory(..)`

Comment: How do you come up with the 60 seconds? Are there any standard practice?

Comment: 60s is what's used in the HttpClient implementation supplied by Google in the SDK (`android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient`) - it adds a few tidbits - such as configuring the socket and connection timeouts, but the motivations behind the choice of timeout is close to non-existant. "Tweak to taste", but 60s is the default behavior of AndroidHttpClient at least.